# How to merge multiple columns in SSRS Matrix report?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, merge, ssrs-2008

I have table with 3 columns **DeveloperName,TimeWorked, Date** and I am using SSRS matrix to create report like

[image]

&

[image]

But I need that **“March 2016”** always should be in centre and for that I need to merge all the columns but **I am unable to merge the columns displaying date (Day1, Day2, Day3 …)**

Can anyone help me how to insert a row with merged columns so that I can show month name in centre?

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding a group (month and year) for the dates.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't add a group add a text box and write an expression.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no way to achieve what you're looking for directly. When using column-groups, you cannot merge a cell from a grouped column with a cell from a non-grouped column.

I ran into this issue myself a year or so ago and ended up with a duct-tape solution. In my case, I have a column group that always returns 7 distinct groups (it's a calendar). The width of each cell of the calendar is 2in exactly, so the heading needs to be "14in" in width. It looks kind of funky when you're designing it but for the user, it turns out perfectly every time.

[image]

Now, it looks like you're working on a calendar-like solution as well, but one that may have a varying number of days displayed. In that case, you could create a textbox that serves as a header for each unique number of columns that could be returned and have each textbox sized and centered appropriately so it sits on top of the tablix and appears to be a centered header. Then, simply set each textbox to only appear when the number of days is appropriate

```
=countDistinct(Fields!Day_Number.Value,"Dataset1")
```

Does that make sense? If you were looking for an elegant solution, I'm afraid I don't have one for you.